# Webpack 4. Does not copy files to actual output folder when webpack-dev-server is used

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

When I used *webpack-dev-server* Webpack4 doesn't create folder *'dist'* with file *main.js*.

My *package.json*

```
  {
  "name": "webpack-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.20.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

My *webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');
module.export = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    }
}
```

But if there is `"dev": "webpack --mode production"` in *package.json* file, folder 'dist' with *main.js* file create.
Why it doesn't work when I use *webpack-dev-server*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpac-dev-server uses [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) and accordingly to its docs:

> No files are written to disk, rather it handles files in memory

Files are served from memory, not from disk. That is why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`writeToDisk`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#writetodisk=) option:

```
devServer: {
  devMiddleware: {
    writeToDisk: true,
  },
},
```